# C++ or MATLAB Library for 3D Graphics for use in Physics Simulation

Tags: c++, matlab, physics, simulation

I'm looking for a library I can use for C++ or MATLAB so that I can do some rigid-body and particle simulations which I can then render and view.

I'd like to be able to use a library to draw particles or rigid bodies and then programmatically specify rotation, translation, etc.

Additionally, I'd like for the library to have the smallest learning curve possible.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Matlab has some great plotting tools built-in and ready to go; why would you want an external library also for Matlab?

Comment: This question could now go to: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Open Scene Graph in c++:

http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg

That library wraps openGL and allows great rendering and has some really good tutorials.

http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/wiki/Support/Tutorials

You will be able to define objects positions by their transform from the 0,0,0 frame allowing to to move objects easily in a physics emulation style.

Hope this helps.